# Next.js multiple class scss from different files

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, react-component

A long search for information about this did not lead to success, so I would like to ask...

I have a component for creating "h1-h6" tags with their own styles:

```
import {HTagProps} from './HTag.props'
import styles from './HTag.module.scss'

export const HTag = ({children, h, ...props}: HTagProps) => {
    switch (h) {
        case 'h1':
            return (<h1 className={styles.h1} {...props}>{children}</h1>)
        case 'h2':
            return (<h2 className={styles.h2} {...props}>{children}</h2>)
        case 'h3':
            return (<h3 className={styles.h3} {...props}>{children}</h3>)
        case 'h4':
            return (<h4 className={styles.h4} {...props}>{children}</h4>)
        case 'h5':
            return (<h5 className={styles.h5}{...props}>{children}</h5>)
        case 'h6':
            return (<h6 className={styles.h6} {...props}>{children}</h6>)
        default:
            return <></>
    }
}
```

And it works well
[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNeoH.jpg)

But when I use my component by adding a new class to it, for example, to add color and position, then my built-in component classes h1-h6 are removed

```
<HTag className={styles.slider_top__title} h={'h1'}>
    Make storytime magical
</HTag>
```

[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwVse.png)

Is there any way I can make both classes work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concat 2 className together

```
 export const HTag = ({children, className h, ...props}: HTagProps) => {
    switch (h) {
        case 'h1':
            return (<h1 className={`${styles.h1} ${className}`} {...props}>{children}</h1>)
        case 'h2':
            return (<h2 className={`${styles.h2} ${className}`} {...props}>{children}</h2>)
        case 'h3':
            return (<h3 className={`${styles.h3} ${className}`} {...props}>{children}</h3>)
        case 'h4':
            return (<h4 className={`${styles.h4} ${className}`} {...props}>{children}</h4>)
        case 'h5':
            return (<h5 className={`${styles.51} ${className}`}{...props}>{children}</h5>)
        case 'h6':
            return (<h6 className={`${styles.h6} ${className}`} {...props}>{children}</h6>)
        default:
            return <></>
    }
}
```

or you can use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```
import {HTagProps} from './HTag.props'
import styles from './HTag.module.scss'
import cn from 'classnames';

export const HTag = ({children, className, h, ...props}: HTagProps) => {
    switch (h) {
        case 'h1':
            return (<h1 className={cn(styles.h1, className)} {...props}>{children}</h1>)
        case 'h2':
            return (<h2 className={cn(styles.h2, className)} {...props}>{children}</h2>)
        case 'h3':
            return (<h3 className={cn(styles.h3, className)} {...props}>{children}</h3>)
        case 'h4':
            return (<h4 className={cn(styles.h4, className)} {...props}>{children}</h4>)
        case 'h5':
            return (<h5 className={cn(styles.h5, className)}{...props}>{children}</h5>)
        case 'h6':
            return (<h6 className={cn(styles.h6, className)} {...props}>{children}</h6>)
        default:
            return <></>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes we can add it like this

```
<HTag className={`${styles.slider_top__title} ${styles.h1}`} h={'h1'}>
    Make storytime magical
</HTag>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).